# What's the difference between a closed set and a bounded set? (basic real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

This is perhaps a stupid question.

I see that you can have a bounded set that's not closed, for instance (0,2) in which the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with elements $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ never reaches 0 for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

But how can you have a closed set that's not bounded?

Comment: Take ${\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\mathbb{R}$ is for example closed, since its complement is the emptyset $\varnothing$ but clearly $\mathbb{R}$ is not bounded.

Comment: That's of course correct. I guess my consolation prize is that I was correct in that it was a stupid question.

Comment: @Mathaniel You were correct in asking it, simply because it was not clear to you (which bothered you). It is not stupid to ask a question in that situation. Can the question then still be marked as stupid?...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thinking of "closed sets" as sets in which cauchy sequences converge, you should think of them as "complements of open sets". Then it becomes obvious because if you take any bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}$, its complement will be an unbounded closed set in $\mathbb{R}$..

Comment: That recipe can only be followed if there is already a notion of open sets. I hope there is, but am not sure (the tag topology is missing). It can happen that one starts with closed sets, and that open sets are introduced as their complements.